# Unable to wrap a long word in table when visualforce page is rendered as PDF

Tags: visualforce

I have seen lot of questions which are related to my question. Is there any solution found. I have 6 columns in my table. If the value of the cell in any one of the columns is long and exceeds the column width then it's not getting broken and is overflowing to next column. I have tried all ways such as word-wrap, break-word etc but I am unable to solve it. Kindly help.

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!studyCountry.Events}" var="event">
    <tr style="font-size: 80%">                
   <td valign="top" style="word-wrap: break-all; font-size:12px; padding: 4px;"><apex:outputText value="{!event.AG_Activity_Categories__c}"/></td>
 <td valign="top" style="word-wrap: break-all; font-size:12px; padding: 4px;"><apex:outputText value="{!event.Subject}"/></td>
```

Comment: Please refer to this solution this should work :- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005FsgIAE

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a work-around is "overflow: hidden". Yes, it cuts off excess, but as far as I know, you cannot make the PDF renderer break words at arbitrary points with just styling.

Another solution is to inject `<wbr/>` between every character of your output string. For that you would need to have your controller provide the texts, instead of reading directly from an object. This inserts a breaking opportunity for the renderer.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488950/css-to-break-a-line-only-on-a-certain-character/24489931#24489931